# css selectors to apply style

Tags: css, css-selectors

I need to apply some style on elements in the following scenarios

1)

```
<span class="abc">
   <span>test</span>
</span>
```

in the above scenario i need some styles to apply to the child span tag of a span having class "abc"

2)

```
<span class="abc">testing123</span>
```

in the above scenario i need to apply some style to only spans with class "abc"

Any help would be great

Thanks!

Comment: We're here to help with your code, not to code for you.

Comment: This is a reasonably quick and decent intro to CSS: http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/

Comment: Or this:http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**scene 1:**

```
.abc span{color:red}
```

**scene 2:**

```
span.abc{color:orange}
```

**Edit:**

```
.abc{border:1px solid #FFF; color:#F00}
.abc span{color:orrange}
```

Comment: Just to let you know, this came up in the low quality posts queue, I'd recommend adding some explanation to your answer on why this works.

Comment: sorry about not adding more information, i am aware of how to handle both cases separately but page could have both different scenarios, i need to add red color and white border to both selectors, when a span contains another span i need to apply a style and also same style would be applied when a span does not have span.

Comment: Your objective is not yet clear, but I have tried to do a fix for you.

Answer (score 0):

Basic CSS

1)

```
.abc > span {
your styles here;
}
```

2)

```
span.abc {
your styles here;
}
```

Comment: sorry about not adding more information, i am aware of how to handle both cases separately but page could have both different scenarios, i need to add red color and white border to both selectors, when a span contains another span i need to apply a style and also same style would be applied when a span does not have span.